# Setting Visiblity of panel inside of formview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a FormView that has elements that I want to make available to different users depending on the users access permissions.  I have encased each of these inside of a panel and ID'd the panel so that I can call them out from the code behind potentially drilling into the FormView with FindControl but have been unsuccessful so far in getting it worked out.

I've never had much luck with FindControl and was wondering if some of you that are more knowledgeable about it could point me in the right direction here is an example of my code on the aspx and C# code behind that IS NOT working out!

If this were functioning then I would place conditionals to for valid groups under this protected void for this panel to allow these users access to this panel and likewise do the same for other panels where permission was applied.

In this way I would be presenting a custom FormView for each user group based on my ACL.  But I just can't get through my head how to drill in with the FindControl properly.

ASPX SAMPLE:

```
<asp:FormView Width="100%" ID="ChangeFormFV" DefaultMode="Insert" runat="server" DataKeyNames="CAssetID" DataSourceID="UpdateSqlDataSource">
<InsertItemTemplate>
    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="ShortDescPnl" Visible="false">
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="LongDescPnl" Visible="false">
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="AddNotesPnl" Visible="false">
    </asp:Panel>
    <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="ManufacturerPnl" Visible="false">
    </asp:Panel>
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Insert" CommandName="Insert" ID="InsertButton" CausesValidation="True" />&nbsp;<asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Cancel" CommandName="Cancel" ID="InsertCancelButton" CausesValidation="False" />
</ItemTemplate>
```

C# Codebehind (not working):

```
protected void ChangeFormFV_Databound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["SessionUType"].ToString() == "ITSec")
        {
            ChangeFormFV.Row.FindControl("ShortDescPnl.visiblity")="true";
        }
    }
```

Appreciate any help that can be offered, been searching for references and reading all I can but just not getting what I need from my results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `FindControl` method returns the actual control.  Set the visibility on the control itself.  Something like this:

```
Panel control = ChangeFormFV.Row.FindControl("ShortDescPnl") as Panel;
if (control != null)
    control.Visible = true;
```

Comment: this appears to be reading the value. What I need to be able to do is set the value to true or false via the code behind.

Comment: @KenCarter: What do you mean by "reading the value"?  The last line of code here assigns a value.

Comment: My bad ... totally missed that... Okay I tried using that inside a page loader and it didn't like that.. then everywhere else... so I'm missing where I might use that. Perhaps I'm missing an include? What it seems to be choking on the ChangeFormFV  telling me that "The name 'ChangeFormFV' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: @KenCarter: Is this code on the same page?  Does a property for the `asp:FormView` control exist in that class?  Normally the designer takes care of creating it for you.

Comment: No it is in the code behind page.  You're saying your example would live on the aspx page?

Comment: @KenCarter: This example would be in the code-behind.  But the `ChangeFormFV` property has to exist on that class.  Normally the forms designer adds it automatically.  But whatever adds or doesn't add it, it needs to exist in order to be used.  Or is this `asp:FormView` nested within another control and it would exist in there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121068/discussion-between-ken-carter-and-david).

Comment: I jumped to chat to continue ...but to answer your last question.. the FV is not nested under another control.. it DOES have other controls nested inside of it but it is top level.   I just tried creating another FV to see if it would create something on the code-behind and it did not either. so something seems gnarled based on your information provided.

Comment: @KenCarter: Did you also check the designer.cs code file?  Keep in mind that the "code behind" is usually two files (partial classes) to separate the auto-generated stuff from the developer-written stuff.  Anything the designer creates should be in that other file.

Comment: Here is what I found in the desiner.CS file related to the FV.. protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.FormView ChangeFormFV;   .... so it was created there. Still baffling why in the aspx.cs it shows the the ChangeFormFV as not existing in the current context.

Comment: Let us continue this discussion in [Chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121068/discussion-between-ken-carter-and-david).

Comment: @David-after much consternation David my good man, the issue is resolved. Your answer was spot on but what had happened was a VS blowout had taken place.  On the advice of someone else I simple rebuilt the aspx page fresh and copies the text over then retyped the aspx.cs code and no more issue!  So now it looks like your solution is working I have a lot of code to work to do all these field up but it looks like I'm on the right track now. No errors at this point but it is not changing the visibility and I have to figure that out.. maybe a post back issue.

Comment: @KenCarter: If it's not taking effect then the first step would be to put some debugging breakpoints throughout the code-behind.  Specifically on the line which sets the visibility, but also on any lines anywhere which could *affect* the visibility.  A common example could be re-binding the control in `Page_Load` which would clobber changes to the control made elsewhere.

Comment: @David- I'm an idiot! My ACL flag is admin the test condition I was running against was different in my code test so OF COURSE it bypassed the condition.. We ARE GOOD!  SUCCESS!! Thanks David!